Inject custom components section from API
I need to load  which contains custom angular component embedded into it coming from API call from content management system as part of ngOnInit function to Angular template dynamically in browser.
<span>
  I accept terms & conditions and the
  <some-custom-tag label=“consent” (onClick)=“openModalDialog()”> 
  </some-custom-tag>
</span>

This above span comes from content management system as part of api call in ngOnInit.
I need to add them dynamically to my template in specific location.

Maybe this helps: https://rangle.io/blog/how-to-render-dynamic-components-in-angular

What have you tried? What's the problem did you have?
